# d3 promise start immediatelly - does not wait for data

Tags: node.js, d3.js, es6-promise

I'm new around here. I have a problem with node.js with combination of EJS template system and D3.js render library.

node.js file:

```
router.post('/foo', function(req, res) {
  fs.unlink('./public/d3.json'); // we delete old data (if exist)
  res.render('foo'); // page render

  //lets suppose that here we request some async data and put them to the array via promises

  let array = []; // our array with data

  Promise.all(array).then(function(all) { //when we download all the necessary data...
    var newArray = JSON.stringify(array);
    fs.writeFile('./public/d3.json', newArray, 'utf-8', function(err) { //we write it to file - so chart file bellow can render it
      if (err) {                                                                        
        console.log('writing public/d3.json file with newArray failure] - ' + err);
      }
      else {
        console.log('public/d3.json file with content of newArray has been created.');
      }
    });
  });
}
module.exports = router;
```

my EJS file looks like:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="chart"></div>
<script>
<% include ../public/d3.js %> // d3 library
<% include ../public/d3_chart.js %> // chart render code
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

my chart file looks like:

```
d3.json("../public/d3.json", cb);

function cb(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    if (data) { // render chart
    }
}
```

But this is not working. It's not render anything - probably cause d3.json file does not have data on it when ejs template run d3_chart.js. But shouldn't promise wait for data and then render the chart? Otherwise whats the point of using promises in d3? How to make it work? I'm feeling like I missing something here and need an advice. Thanks.

Comment: on the server you route the URL `/foo` to service a json file or you write to `public/d3.json` but you request `../d3js/d3.json`. What do you see in the server log and what on the browser console and network tab?

Comment: Yea it's a simply mistype - on server code is fine, file path it's not the case.  Now back to the question, when i delete d3.json file at start and run the app i got error that there is no d3.json. If I don't delete it, graph is showed with outdated data. So it read file immediately after d3_chart.js is loaded... promise don't wait for data. I just used socket.io for transferring data, but I would really like to know WHY it's not working with d3.json command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the promise on the d3 side but the way you handle the request on the server.

On the server you set up some asynchronous process to construct the response you want to service. The request handler will **not** wait for the asynchronous processes to be ready to create a responds.

**Don't** do asynchronous stuff in the handling of a request on the server if you want to service the result immediately. Using a local server file is very bad if you have multiple requests from different users. (This is one way to get the data from another user.) You need to wait on the server for the results.

Comment: "The request handler will not wait for the asynchronous processes to be ready to create a responds."got it.But socket.io is working great-server get data (in request 'queue' - router.POST) asynchronously,work on it, send it to the user. "Don't do asynchronous stuff in the handling of a request on the server if you want to service the result immediately."ok I will keep it in mind,but here data can be passed latter on."Using a local server file is very bad if you have multiple requests from different users."yea I suppose I will need to make some random file name. What about last sentence?

Comment: @Thave1957: then you have to look for your webserver how to do async work to service a request (postpone the response to the user based on the result of async result)